# produce Sparql S-Expressions (SSE) by redland librdf

Tags: c++, sparql, redland

Apache Jena/arq has a 'qparse' tool that parse a SPARQL query and generate SPARQL Algebra output (in SSE format).
But Apache Jena' API has been written in Java. So I use Redlan librdf (C++) for parsing queries. Dose librdf do that? generating SPARQL parsed data in SSE format?
(I know that there is a special format with librdf rasqal tool:

```
roqet: Querying from file q4.rq
Query:
query verb: SELECT
query projected variable names (2): y, givenName
query bound variables (2): y, givenName
query Group graph pattern[0] {
  sub-graph patterns (2) {
    Basic graph pattern[1] #0 {
      triples {
        triple #0 { triple(variable(y), uri<http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#Family>, variable(givenName)) }
      }
  }
  Filter graph pattern[2] #1 {
      filter { expr(op regex(expr(variable(givenName)), expr(string("s")), expr(string("i"))))}
    }
  }
}
roqet: Query has a variable bindings result
result: [y=blank genid1, givenName=string("Smith")]
result: [y=blank genid2, givenName=string("Smith")]
result: [y=blank genid3, givenName=string("Jones")]
result: [y=blank genid4, givenName=string("Jones")]
roqet: Query returned 4 results
```

)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough to provide a conclusive answer but, based on [rasqal_algebra.c](https://github.com/dajobe/rasqal/blob/master/src/rasqal_algebra.c), it looks like redland does have this sort of intermediate representation.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know why you want to do this.  SSE is not standardised and is mainly a useful debugging output of ARQ.  Most libraries are going to have some sort of intermediate representation of SPARQL queries but details will vary because of design decisions and usage patterns of that library

Comment: @RobV , I'd like having a DOM of sparql query in my c++ library, so I think using the sse for handle that. (like JSON object to parse and access json strings)